# Problems with FTP connection via Tramp

Tags: osx, tramp, ftp

I try to create FTP connection via Tramp, but the output I get on AngeFTP is:

```bash
ftp> open android.local
ftp: Can't connect to `192.168.0.21:21': Connection refused
ftp: Can't connect to `android.local:ftp'
ftp>
```

I have tried many different options, but nothing works. SFTP works fine, but I can't get FTP working. Here is my config:

/etc/hosts

```bash
192.168.0.21 android.local
```

~/.netrc

```bash
machine android.local
    login foo
    password foo
    port 2221
```

init.el

```lisp
(set-register ?a (cons 'file "/ftp:foo@android.local:#2221:/storage/0123-4567"))
```

Any ideas?

---

EDIT:
I was able to connect via ftp client from the terminal (outside Tramp) with the command `ftp ftp://foo:foo@192.168.0.21:2221`, but can't replicate that via Tramp.

Comment: "I try to create FTP connection via Trump" ... that's not possible anymore since Jan 20th.

Comment: Seriously: your FTP server seems to be located on an Android device. Are you able to connect with a vanilla FTP client, from a shell? And, btw, I'm not sure that Ange-FTP is able to read multiple line .netrc entries.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus yes, I found it best, OS agnostic way to transfer files to Android devices. I used to use FileZilla for this, but it would be easier by just using Tramp. Obviously you need FTP server app.

Comment: Honestly, this needs debugging. Not possible on SX. Pls contact us via the `tramp-devel@gnu.org` ML.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell what I should put into the message, if the copy of this post will be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, even a reference to this discussion would do. The point is, that email exchange is better suited to give you instructions for tests.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. You said that "creating FTP connection via Trump is not possible since Jan 20th.", but you want me to leave a message on ML about it as it would be possible. I don't want to waste anybody time, if this kind of connection is not possible. I was able to connect to FTP using terminal client outside Emacs, I updated the post with information.

Comment: Please read letter-by-letter what I have said :-) And think about the date, what happened then.

Comment: I read entire conversation but if the FTP is not supported I don't understand what needs debugging in your opinion.

Comment: Oh my god. You have said initially "I try to create FTP connection via Trump", and I made a joke (I thought) saying, that this what-so-ever person in not related to Tramp.

Comment: Haha ok sorry, yes, I made a typo which I fixed a day later. I'm not US person. I thought you are referring to the information I read over the internet that FTP is now handled by AngeFtp so Tramp FTP support was abandoned. I will send a report then. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the example. `"/ftp:foo@android.local:#2221:/storage/0123-4567"` must be `"/ftp:foo@android.local#2221:/storage/0123-4567"`.